# What is the latest model Macbook Pro that has user-serviceable RAM and/or SDD?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade

Since roughly 2016, all Macbook Pros have been non-upgradeable.  What is the latest model Macbook Pro that has user-serviceable RAM and/or SDD?

Comment: Some research will tell you this - personally I find Mactracker to be excellent and works on phone, ipad and mac.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't see this information in Mactracker. It reports how much RAM, and storage sizes, but not whether they are soldered in.

Comment: Well, I see "Built-In" memory specified on later machine but not earlier ones... Do you think that is telling you what you want? Granted they don't refer to "soldered"...

Comment: EveryMac has this info unambiguously, scroll down to "Standard RAM" and it tells you. https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.3-quad-core-13-2020-4-thunderbolt-3-ports-scissor-specs.html